# Installing sonata ecommerce bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata

I need to use sonata e commerce capabilities in my project but I have't had any success so far. It seems that there is not a compatible version with my current setup.
Here is my composer file

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.3",
  "ext-soap": "*",
  "ext-gd": "*",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-last-tweets-bundle": "*",

  "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle":"^1.8",
    "twig/extensions":"1.2",
  "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "dev-master",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.4.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.x.dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.x.dev",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "2.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.x.dev",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.2.*"


},
```

When I run `composer require sonata-project/ecommerce-bundle` composer cant find a version that works with my current setup.
The error message that I get is

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for sonata-project/ecommerce ^2.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/ecommerce[2.0.0].
- sonata-project/ecommerce 2.0.0 requires sonata-project/block-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/block-bundle[3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Please help. I have more than 3 days trying to get this working.

Comment: Did you try to run this command :  "php composer.phar self-update"

Comment: @Letsrocks this is not a composer problem. Its a version incompatibility problem. My question is which version of sonata ecommerce can be used with my current version of the other sonata bundles.

Comment: What if you change  "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.2.*" by  "sonata-project/block-bundle": "3*" in your composer.json ??

Comment: @Carlos there are other bundles in the project that depends on that bundle version, so your suggestion is not an option. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues are going to be fixed when this PR is merged: https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/pull/583

So just wait a few days, or patch some code ;)